# Is really Spring Cloud Hystrix project deprecated?

Tags: spring, resilience4j, hystrix-dashboard

How we can use Hystrix in spring cloud project whereas the spring current version does not support this circuit breaker and suggests Resilience4j. In other words using Resilience4j , how it is possible to apply additional capabilities such dashboard , turbine and so on.
Thanks for answers!